# Android to external bluetooth polling

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, inputstream, polling

I'm trying to pulse my bluetooth dongle, to see if it is range.
Every second my Android sends a char to the dongle, which then responds with a char. If there is no response, or the char is wrong, then it should conclude that there is no connection.

I'm able to send from Android to dongle (attached to MCU), and the dongle is able to respond.
All I need is a simple way to read each char (when received) to compare it. I'm trying to do it in a seperate thread to make it run in its own loop.

Here is my code so far, but I think I might be off, so if you could give me a pointer!

```
void readFromInputStream()
{ 
    Thread readFromInputStream = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            String streng = "";

            try
            {
                //just 100 times for now
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {

                     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

                    if(in.read() == 'z')
                    {
                        //set variable or something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //do something else
                    }

                    writeTerminal('z');
                    sleep(1000);

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Threading", e.toString());
            }
            finally
      {
                finish();
      }
        }
    };
    readFromInputStream.start();
    }
}
```

But it seems every time I try and evaluate something it freezes!

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the Q at hand but you may want to be a little careful with using polling on Android - you'll kill the battery, especially polling every 1 second.

Comment: Actually I'd rather avoid the polling part, but I was hoping that disconnecting the bluetooth dongle (not the android bluetooth) would throw an exception when trying to write to it, but it doesn't seem to work, so I came up with the polling solution....sigh!

Comment: try doing a device discovery / inquiry or a remote name request to check if the device is in range...

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but device discovery is just so slow...unless you somehow can ask if a certain device is present instead of searching and filtering all devices!.

Answer (score 0):

Just try connecting to the device and if the connection goes through you know it is present, and immediately disconnect.

Comment: but wouldn't I then have to toggle connect? My solution so far, is that I found out I can 'spam' the connection in a async thread. If there is no device in the other end, then eventually (after 50 bytes or so) the 'pipe is broken' (some kind of outputStreamBuffer overflow)...so that's my solution for now.

Comment: But then in order to reconnect again, I need to disable/enable Bluetooth,

Comment: Or do you think I can just keep "resuming bluetooth" (even if connected) and then catch the exception there?...and if exception then close connection?

Comment: can you elaborate on what is "resuming bluetooth" ? Also I am wondering why you need to poll for device proximity ? Just connecting when you want to will determine if the device is present it will connect, else it will fail.